# IPtables: ipset filtering through existing forward rules

Tags: routing, openvpn, iptables

I've followed a guide to set up a raspberry pi to connect to a VPN, then NAT the traffic from my LAN to the VPN in order to protect it.

I'm also using it for DNS filtering (adblocking).

Domain filtering doesn't filter out the IPs I don't like, so I'm trying to learn about ipsets to prohibit communication with vast areas of the Internet.

Currently, my script to do all this looks as such:

```
iptables -F

ipset restore < /etc/ipset-blacklist/ip-blacklist.restore

iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set --match-set blacklist src -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set blacklist src -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -m set --match-set blacklist src -j DROP

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -L
```

This works!

But I don't understand why, and I don't think I need all three blacklist rules for INPUT, FORWARD & OUTPUT - I feel like I've achieved a working result the wrong way - and without understanding it.

Can anyone wiser than I see what I'm trying to do, what I've achieved and where I've got wrong please?

Also, what is the "1" for in this line:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set --match-set blacklist src -j DROP
```

This is the goal, which is already somewhat achieved:
[LAN Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzBmK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Edit::
The "1" is for the order of the rule.

The FORWARD chain is the only necessary chain, not all three.

I assume this is because all the traffic is being forwarded.